# Separating dataTables column sorting

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have attached the click event of a dataTables th to something else and I wouldn't wish for the column to be sorted when the user does this other thing.

However, I still would like to have the columns sortable.

Is there an easy way to assign sorting of a column to a separate button (just the up/down arrows graphic) instead of the whole th?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the fnSort() function? You can bind it to anything.